# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: script.R

Tags: r, docker, snakemake

I was trying to execute R script through snakefile on docker container. It stopped with the PermissionError pointing out the line calls the R script. Here is the message:

```
RuleException:
PermissionError in line 336 of /PATH/my_snakefile.smk:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/PATH/my_script.R'

Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: .snakemake/875284.snakemake.log
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM cbuatmbc/project

COPY . /PATH/my_project

RUN chmod -R 2775 /PATH/my_project

RUN conda upgrade -n base conda

RUN conda env create -f /PATH/condafiles/my_project_ymlfile.yml

ENV PATH="/PATH/bin:/PATH/bin:$PATH" \
PERL5LIB="/PATH/lib/perl:$PERL5LIB" \
PERL_CPANM_HOME="/PATH/builds/perl5" \
PERL_CPANM_OPT="-l /PATH/local --no-man-pages --save-dists=/PATH    /PATH/local/src/perl5" \
PYTHONPATH="/PATH/local/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH" \
R_PROFILE_USER="/PATH/my_project/.Rprofile" \
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV="my_project" \
CONDA_PREFIX="/PATH/my_project"

WORKDIR /PATH/my_project/dataset

ENTRYPOINT ["/PATH/local/dockerfiles/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["snakemake --dag | dot -Tsvg > dag.svg"]
```

While in interactive mode I am able to run the code through r base, I cannot run it using `docker run` because of the mentioned error.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675000/permission-denied-error-from-docker-container-in-snakemake